# Multiple apps in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have no clue why users with `Staff status` don't see all apps. As `Superuser` I can see all 3 apps installed:

- Backend
- Backoffice
- Polls

As a user with `Staffstatus` I have only `Backoffice` available. For each app I did in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from <AppName>.models import <Class1, Class2, ...>

...
...
admin.site.register(Class1)
admin.site.register(Class2)
...
admin.site.register(ClassN)
```

Here is a screenshot of the Permissions area:

[image]

Where are polls? Where is backend?
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint everyone, but after a lot of searching and trial and error, I found out the right solution was to add to all the model Classes in the `backend.models` the following:

```
class Meta:
   app_label = 'backend'
```

Now these models are visible in the admin interface when `admin.autodiscover` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need change permissions to be able to view the app. Django doesn't have a separate “view” permission.

Comment: what do you mean I need to change the permission? It's not there, so how can I change it???

Comment: @Oz123 You need to give Staff users change permissions on whatever app you want them to be able to view.

Comment: i would have done so if i could, the whole point of the question is exactly this : the other apps are not there to choos from...

Comment: @Oz123 Have you logged in as a super admin and tried assigning the permissions to other staff users there? It's convenient to create a group with the desired permissions then add the required users to that group

Comment: yes I did log is a super user, the apps are not there to choose from. So I can create the groups you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in admin.py:

```
class ClassAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):

  def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
      if db_field.name == 'user_permissions':
          kwargs['queryset'] = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label="{{NAME_OF_APP}}")
      return super(ClassAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request=request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: in which admin.py in all of them? remember I have 3 of them, one for each app ...